# Attribute Group doesn't up immediately under Contact Data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder, attribute-group

I have been facing this weird thing for quite a while now. I create an Attribute Group under Contact Builder but it doesn't show up immediately under Contact Data in the journey builder activities (decision split, event source etc.)

I wait for few hours and it comes up. Is it expected behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Journey Builder caches Attribute Sets on load. You will need to [force refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Bypass_your_cache) Journey Builder after creating Attribute Groups and Attribute Sets. You should then see the new Attribute Sets available in Journey Builder Activities.

Comment: Ahh! Why my mind couldn't think of this?
Thanks Eliot!